# How to prevent Opencart From stripping an input?

Tags: opencart

I have made some changes to add caption to opencart owl carousel , I am using title input to store some captions that contains html codes .
Opencart strips input html codes and then shows them as plain text.
How can i prevent Opencart From stripping banners title input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$my_banner_caption = html_entity_decode($my_banner_caption, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: مجتبی خان اگر تلگرام دارین بفرمایین خوشحال میشم رابطه کاری  و علمی داشته باشیم

Comment: سلام، ممنون، بله، sabeti05 هستم.